# keyListenner and mousemove

Tags: java, awt

```
 import java.applet.Applet;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Event;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
 import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Drawing extends Applet implements KeyListener {
 /**
  * 
  */

 char c;
 int xCoord, yCoord, xCoord2, yCoord2;
 int lastx = getX();
 int lasty = getY();
 int count = 0;
 public void paint(Graphics g) {


  switch (c) {
   case 'b':
    {
     g.setColor(Color.black);
     break;
    }
   case 'p':
    {
     g.setColor(Color.pink);
    }
  }
  g.drawLine(xCoord, yCoord, xCoord2, yCoord2);
 }
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

 }
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

 }

 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
  c = e.getKeyChar();
  System.out.println("check if it run");
  paint(this.getGraphics());

 }
 public boolean mouseMove(Event e, int x, int y) {
  System.out.println("mouse");
  xCoord2 = x;
  yCoord2 = y;
  xCoord = lastx;
  yCoord = lasty;
  lastx = x;
  lasty = y;
  if (xCoord != 0 || yCoord != 0)
   this.paint(getGraphics());

  return true;
 }


}
```

why is my key typed method not running , I want to changed the color through key,but it is not running, the code runs good , but I can't change the color through typing.pleases help me.The goal of this program is almost completed but I can't change the color.ssss s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s

Comment: Indentation, please. No one should have to read code like this.

Comment: 1) Applets are deprecated, you should stop using them; 2) NEVER use `getGraphics` and certainly never try and call `paint` yourself, this is not how painting works - take a look at [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to understand how painting works and how you can make use of it; 3) Like all questions on `KeyListener` not working, use the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Applets are deprecated, you should stop using them
2. NEVER use `getGraphics` and certainly never try and call `paint` yourself, this is not how painting works - take a look at [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to understand how painting works and how you can make use of it
3. Like all questions on `KeyListener` not working, use the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead